# Mutithreaded database in C++ using reader writer approach stuck half way

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I am writing a multithreading database. I will receive multiple queries from multiple tables. I classified them into different tables and adopted the reader/writer approach. Multiple readers can read at the same time but only one writer can write. Different from traditional r/w I forced the query to be executed in the order to ensure correctness.

My problem is that, there is always some query getting stuck when there is more than 1 thread in my thread pool. This is not a common issue, if I am running on a test set with 10,000 queries there will be no issue. However, each time I run with 300,000 queries, there will be some random writer getting stuck. If I am running on just 1 thread in the pool, everything is just fine. Each time I lock a mutex or semaphore, I unlock it immediately, what could be the issue?

**Original Input:**

`Q1 writer table 1`

`Q2 writer table 2`

`Q3 reader table 1`

`Q4 reader table 1`

`Q5 writer table 2`

**Modified:**

Store in a query table `Qtable`, which holds the executable query obj, the corresponding query properties. Different tables will run in parallel and store the results in a global result vector according to the global id.

`vec_qvec[table ==1]`  `vec_qpvec[table==1]`

`[0] queryobj`         `[0] iswriter, global id = 1`

`[1] queryobj`         `[0] isreader, global id = 3`

`[2] queryobj`         `[0] isreader, global id = 4`

`vec_qvec[table ==2]`

`[0] table 2`         `[0] iswriter, global id = 2`

`[1] table 2`         `[0] iswriter, global id = 5`

Code:

```
//rwinfo holds the shared semaphore for a table, 
//and store the current number of readers and whether there is a writer working.
auto readerexe = [](const int &_id, struct rwinfo &_rwinfo){
    //exe the query and store the result in queryresult obj
    QueryResult::Ptr result = (Qtable.vec_qvec[_rwinfo.tableid][_id])->execute();
    
    mtx_queryresult_vec.lock();
        QUERY_RESULT_VEC.emplace_back(std::move(result));
        QUERY_RESULT_index.emplace_back(Qtable.vec_qpvec[_rwinfo.tableid][_id].id);
        //push the result into global result vector and record the global id    
        
        if (QUERY_RESULT_index.size() == COUNTER){
            sem_post(&_rwinfo.FINISHED);
            //wake up the main thread to tell it everything is finished
        }
        
        cerr_mtx.lock();
            cerr<<"qr: "<<QUERY_RESULT_index.size()<<",Finish ID:"<< Qtable.vec_qpvec[_rwinfo.tableid][_id].id <<", table id: "<<_rwinfo.tableid <<", id:"<<_id<<endl;
        cerr_mtx.unlock();
    mtx_queryresult_vec.unlock();
    
    //reduce the number of readers
    sem_wait(&_rwinfo.reader_reading);
        reader_is_reading[_rwinfo.tableid]--;
    sem_post(&_rwinfo.reader_reading);

};

auto writerexe = [](const int &_id,struct rwinfo &_rwinfo){
    //execute
    QueryResult::Ptr result = (Qtable.vec_qvec[_rwinfo.tableid][_id])->execute();

    mtx_queryresult_vec.lock();
        QUERY_RESULT_VEC.emplace_back(std::move(result));
        QUERY_RESULT_index.emplace_back(Qtable.vec_qpvec[_rwinfo.tableid][_id].id);
        if (QUERY_RESULT_index.size() == COUNTER){
            sem_post(&_rwinfo.FINISHED);
        }
        //insert result
    mtx_queryresult_vec.unlock();
    cerr_mtx.lock();
        cerr<<"qr: "<<QUERY_RESULT_index.size()<<",Finish ID:"<< Qtable.vec_qpvec[_rwinfo.tableid][_id].id <<", table id: "<<_rwinfo.tableid <<", id:"<<_id<<endl;
    cerr_mtx.unlock();

    sem_wait(&_rwinfo.writer_working);
        writer_is_working[_rwinfo.tableid] = false;
        //set the writer is working to be false
    sem_post(&_rwinfo.writer_working);
};

auto rwfunc = [](const int &id,struct rwinfo &_rwinfo){
    if(Qtable.vec_qpvec[_rwinfo.tableid][id].iswriter){
        writerexe(id,_rwinfo);
    } else{
        readerexe(id,_rwinfo);
    }
};
```

Main loop to enque the readers and writers to the threadpool:

```
   //loop while the enque numer is smaller than the number of queries
while (quenum < (int) COUNTER){
    //loop through all tables and find enqueable tables
    for (int i = 0; i < (int ) Qtable.tablenum; ++i) {
        //If the capacity of the table is larger than the queries has been enqued
        if ( info_vec[i].vecsize > vect[i]){
                    //if table[i] do not have a working writer
                    if (!writer_is_working[i]){
                        //if table[i],localid[vect[i]] is a writer, vect[i] the counter for each table
                        if (Qtable.vec_qpvec[i][vect[i]].iswriter){
                            if (reader_is_reading[i]==0){
                                // if no reader is reading, enque
                                sem_wait(&info_vec[i].writer_working);
                                    writer_is_working[i] = true;
                                sem_post(&info_vec[i].writer_working);
                            } else{
                                // wait for next time since there is some reading reading
                                   cerr_mtx.lock();
                                        cerr<<"waiting for reader:"<<Qtable.vec_qpvec[i][vect[i]].id<<endl;
                                   cerr_mtx.unlock();
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else{
                            // it is a reader and no writing is writing
                            sem_wait(&info_vec[i].reader_reading);
                                reader_is_reading[i]++;
                            sem_post(&info_vec[i].reader_reading);
                        }
                        //push the job to the thread pool
                        pool.push(rwfunc,vect[i],info_vec[i]);
                        quenum++;
                        vect[i]++;
                        // increase the total number enqued, local table number enqued
                        cerr<<quenum<<"/"<<COUNTER<<", "<<vect[i]<<"/"<<info_vec[i].vecsize<<endl;
                    } else{
                        //writer is writing
                        cerr_mtx.lock();
                        cerr<<"waiting for writer:"<<Qtable.vec_qpvec[i][vect[i]].id<<endl;
                        cerr_mtx.unlock();
                    }
        }
    }
}

cerr<<"Leaving :"<<COUNTER<<endl;
sem_wait(&FINISHED);
cerr<<"Finish waiting"<<endl;
```

Thread pool:

```c
inline void threadManager() {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(JobMutex);
            std::cerr<<"Thread waiting"<<std::endl;
            thread.wait(lock, [this] {return  ID < (int )JobQueue.size() && !JobQueue.empty(); });
        //    std::cerr<<"Thread funish waiting"<<std::endl;
            idmtx.lock();
            //strange bug where it will continue even if the job queue is empty
                if (ID >= (int )(JobQueue).size() || JobQueue.empty()){
                    idmtx.unlock();
                    continue;
                }
                int localint = ID;
                ID++;
            idmtx.unlock();
            lock.unlock();
            //std::cerr<<"\n"<<localint<<std::endl;
            (JobQueue[localint])->execute();

        }
    }
    inline explicit ThreadPool(int _numThreads) : numThreads(_numThreads) {

        int tmp = MAX_THREADS;
        if(numThreads > tmp){
            numThreads = tmp;
        }

        Pool.reserve(numThreads);
        std::cerr<<"Thread pool core num: "<<numThreads<<std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i != numThreads; ++i){
            Pool.emplace_back(std::thread(&ThreadPool::threadManager, this));
            Pool.back().detach();
        }
    }
```

Output log after getting stuck:

```c
waiting for writer:172500
waiting for writer:83579
waiting for writer:272066
waiting for writer:207462
waiting for writer:156791
waiting for writer:172500
waiting for writer:83579
waiting for writer:272066
waiting for writer:207462
waiting for writer:156791
waiting for writer:172500
waiting for writer:83579
waiting for writer:272066
waiting for writer:207462
waiting for writer:156791
waiting for writer:172500
waiting for writer:83579
waiting for writer:272066
waiting for writer:207462
waiting for writer:156791
waiting for writer:172500
waiting for writer:83579
waiting for writer:272066
```

Comment: Is it possible one of your threads have unexpectedly terminated/thrown an exception, leaving a mutex locked?

Comment: You need to make sure that anything between those `lock()` and `unlock()` calls do not `throw`.  That's why using RAII-based locking is preferred, rather than `lock() / unlock()` pairs.

Comment: The problem is that, this code runs well when there is only one thread in the pool. What would make the difference, when I switch to more than one thread?

Comment: *This code runs well when there is only one thread in the pool* -- You could say that for the thousands of badly or incorrectly written multithreaded programs.  Yours is no different -- when you only are doing "x" things everything works, when you increase "x", things break down.  Here is a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046338/vector-erase-function-fails-when-using-high-threads-even-with-mutex-lock#comment114996440_65046338) that illustrates this.  Bottom line is that MT programming requires expert analysis  for things like this, and we don't have a [mcve] to analyze.

Comment: *Each time I lock a mutex or semaphore, I unlock it immediately,* -- `idmtx.unlock();            lock.unlock();` --  This sequence of code is not atomic.  There is no guarantee that a particular thread will execute those two calls in succession without a thread context switch occurring between both of those unlock calls.

Comment: Thanks for  your advice, I'll check that. It is almost impossible to produce a minimal reproducible code, since the test case is over 300,0000 and only with that amount of test cases can I find misbehaviors.

Comment: I changed all mutex.lock and mutex.unlock with unique_lock< mutex> and unique_lock.unlock(), but I still get stuck. Also, I've handled all the exceptions in `QueryResult::Ptr result = (Qtable.vec_qvec[_rwinfo.tableid][_id])->execute();` Even in failed cases will return a failed result object and I found that no query is in execution when I'm stucked. So would you be so kind to provide me with some clues such that I can work on.

Comment: I cannot recommend enough [ThreadSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) for initial automated analysis of what is wrong with your locking. The tool found subtle issues that went unnoticed for years in my projects.

Comment: The code seems to be using semaphores to protect shared variables from race conditions, but nothing prevents the semaphore count going above 1 and allowing multiple threads to race updating the shared variable. You probably need to use binary semaphores, also known as mutexes.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help people help you. Voting to close for the lack of it.